# GIT: How to Jump to Different Branches without Deleting Files

Tags: git, svn, github

This is my flow of work:

Under 'master': git checkout -b branch_x

Under 'branch_x': create and save file 'abc'

Under 'branch_x': git checkout master

Under 'master': git checkout -b branch_y

Under 'branch_y': create and save file 'def'

Now when I try to do pull origin, I got rejected because it says there is a file 'abc' there. If I delete 'abc', the pull origin branch_y goes through, but if I go back to branch_x, 'abc' is gone from there too.

Questions are: 1. Why Branch Y sees 'abc' too? It's created in Branch X! 2. How can I upload whatever I did on Branch Y without touching anything under Branch X?

Thanks!

Comment: If a path is in neither commit, or its content is the same in both commits, git leaves your worktree copy (and any index entry)  alone.

Answer (score 1):

With Git, uncommitted files don't belong to *any* branch. They're just untracked files in your working copy.

After creating your file `abc` on branch `branch_x`, commit the file with

```
git add abc
git commit
```

Then switch branches with `git checkout master`. You'll find that the file `abc` is no longer present.